# validate number with different range in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

In e-commerce system, we have list of postcode and we need to exclude 2 range of numbers for postcode.

For example:
Postcode excluded starting with 1xxxxx & 3xxxxx, but accepted from 6xxxxx.

I have validation code in javascript and needed to add 2 conditions, if number start with 1 and 3, the user have warning message that this postcode not in coverage.

Hope anyone could help.

Code I have currently as below:

```
 return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) &&  /^60/.test(v);
```

Thanks.

Comment: `if (v.match(/[13]\d+/) { alert('Not in Coverage')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will check whether v is as any number([0-9]) except 1 or 3 as the first digit

```
return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) && /^[0-9]/.test(v) && !(/^[13]/.test(v))
```

This will check whether v is as partial of digit as first(6,7,8,9)

```
return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) && /^[6789]/.test(v)
```

By the way, you might also want to check the length and format of the post code in 6 digits({5}). In that case, you can change the phrase as

```
return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) && /^[6789][0-9]{5}$/.test(v)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share my Experience of verifying US postal Codes in Jquery that I have used during a project in Oodles Technologies.

I have solved this problem by using jQuery validation plugin

```
$("#myform").validate({
rules: {
field: {
required: true,
phoneUS: true
}
}
});
```

Files required for this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script
```

It sometimes doesn't work.

To get it working we have to include Jquery addtional-methods.min.js
If still it doesn't work then you have to use following script before validate method which contains regex to validate.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function (phone_number, element) {
            phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");
            return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
                  phone_number.match(/\(?[\d\s]{3}\)[\d\s]{3}-[\d\s]{4}$/);
        }, "Invalid phone number");
```

It finally solve the problem. If you have required some other format then modify above regex according to need.